# Maven dependency convergence mismatch in spring-ws-security regarding org.apache.santuario:xmlsec

Tags: java, spring, apache, maven, spring-ws

With *spring-ws / spring-ws-security 2.4.0.RELEASE* we are getting a *Maven Enforcer plugin* dependency convergence error.

*Apache's xmlsec versions 1.x and 2.x* are transitive dependencies.

Is it safe to exclude the *1.x* versions of **org.apache.santuario:xmlsec**?

```
Dependency convergence error for org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:1.5.8 paths to dependency are:
+-com.acme.web.app:3.14.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-security:2.4.0.RELEASE
    +-org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:1.6.19
      +-org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:1.5.8
and
+-com.acme.web.app:3.14.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-security:2.4.0.RELEASE
    +-org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:1.6.19
      +-org.opensaml:opensaml:2.5.1-1
        +-org.opensaml:openws:1.4.2-1
          +-org.opensaml:xmltooling:1.3.2-1
            +-org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:1.4.4
and
+-com.acme.web.app:3.14.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-security:2.4.0.RELEASE
    +-org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-dom:2.1.4
      +-org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-common:2.1.4
        +-org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:2.0.5
and
+-com.acme.web.app:3.14.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-security:2.4.0.RELEASE
    +-org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-dom:2.1.4
      +-org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-common:2.1.4
        +-org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-impl:3.1.1
          +-org.opensaml:opensaml-security-impl:3.1.1
            +-org.opensaml:opensaml-security-api:3.1.1
              +-org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:2.0.3
```

Comment: Can you also put the dependency declaration here?

Comment: Convergence is very well described here http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html

Comment: Dependency declaration is:

    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
       <version>2.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: Try adding `maven-enforcer-plugin` in your pom as shown in the URL  mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I got this error when added this dependency

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.9.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

As described at https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html, the solution is to exclude duplicate dependencies, but with different versions.